# AnyLogic not properly reading from Excel String Values

Tags: anylogic

I've been seeing a weird AnyLogic behavior where I cannot use boolean operations properly with Excel. For example, if I assign a string value of "x" to a variable from Excel and then check in AnyLogic if that variable is equal to "x", AnyLogic returns false as if the "x" from Excel is different than "x" in AnyLogic.

For simplicity I am sharing a very simplified model highlighting the issue.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/eaa042a4999021c11f4396759a3c9da020210123154728/550611

Has anyone faced such an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/should only use "==" with primitives (int, double, boolean) but with classes you need to use equals(), and String is not a primitive.

Like this:

```
if(excelFile.getCellStringValue(1, 1, 1).equals("x"))
```